# I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?

Tags: support, faq

[This question was adopted/stolen from the RPG Stack Exchange's Meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).

I asked a question about literature that was closed. Someone recommended that I try posting the question on another website. What are some good recommendations for other websites that would be a good fit for questions that would be closed here? In addition, are there any off-line communities (e.g. book clubs?) that would be a good place to discuss questions that would be closed here?

**When answering this question, please post one website per answer. That way people can vote on which suggestions they feel are useful.**

Answer (score 10):

## Your local library

If you have a local library, it is a great resource. They have free books! Librarians are a fantastic resource that can answer all sorts of question. I've gotten book recommendations from librarians, they've helped me with my research... they're a fantastic resource! And many libraries have social groups such as book clubs.

[You can find the location of the nearest local library using a fantastic website called WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/libraries).

Answer (score 9):

## Reddit

Reddit doesn't have a [be nice](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy, which is why I, for the most part, no longer post there. (I used to be a moderator on an active subreddit BTW). But it has some good literary subreddits. [/r/askliterarystudies](http://reddit.com/r/askliterarystudies) is good for academic questions, [/r/books](http://reddit.com/r/books) and [/r/literature](http://reddit.com/r/literature%5C) are good for more casual conversations. It's not particularly my cup of tea, given the lack of a be nice policy, but you might find the site useful.

Also on Reddit:

- [r/shakespeare](https://www.reddit.com/r/shakespeare/): Bill Shaxberd,
- [r/Litterature](https://www.reddit.com/r/Litterature/), aka *Littérature française*, for French literature,
- [r/Buecher - Lies etwas](https://www.reddit.com/r/buecher/) in German (though not limited to books in German),
- [r/Libri](https://www.reddit.com/r/Libri/): "Tutto sui libri e la lettura" (Italian),
- [r/libros](https://www.reddit.com/r/libros/): "El mejor contenido de literatura y libros en español" (Spanish),
- [r/Livros](https://www.reddit.com/r/Livros/) (Portuguese).

Answer (score 8):

## [Goodreads](http://goodreads.com)

Goodreads is a social networking site that allows people to review books. It has a recommendation engine that recommends books based on what you've already read and liked. The site also has social networking features: for example, you can create lists of books and share those lists with friends.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as calling Goodreads a social networking site, but it's good for recommendations. +1, didn't think of this one.

Comment: I disagree. It's much better for networking and recommendations for things your friends are reading about, than genuinely new recommendations.

Answer (score 3):

### [Gnooks](http://www.gnooks.com/)

If you want literature recommendations, try this site. Simply put in three authors you like and it'll recommend a selection of similar authors for you that you can then thumbs up or thumbs down through which it further fine-tunes its selection. Not always accurate, but can be fun and occasionally helpful.

Comment: This looks interesting!

Answer (score 2):

### [NoveList](https://www.ebscohost.com/novelist)

This resource may be available at your local library. If you like a specific genre or something within a genre, then you may use the resource to find your ideal books. A record may show interesting information, such as book reviews, popularity ranking, writing style, a brief summary, and tags that link to other books.

Answer (score 2):

**[etudes-litteraires.com](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/categories/litterature-francaise)**

This site has a discussion forum about French literature (in French).

Answer (score 1):

**[LiteraturForum.de](https://www.literaturforum.de/forum.php)**

This site has a discussion forum about German literature with—in truly German fashion—many subcategories.

Answer (score 1):

[**De Boekgrrls**](http://www.boekgrrls.nl/)

A Dutch-language forum for women who love reading.

Answer (score 1):

**[Klassikerforum](https://klassikerforum.de/forum/)**

A German-language forum for discussing the classics in literature.

Answer (score 1):

**[Literaturforum (Versalia.de)](https://www.versalia.de/forum/index.php)**

The forum of the German-language literature site Versalia.de. The subforums focus on topics such as news or new publications, history & theory of literature, reviews, poetry, prose and translations.