# Are there literature forums for discussing literature in general?

Tags: discussion

Are there literature forums for discussing literature in general, rather than ones focused on questions and answer? I like asking questions a lot, but don't **expect** the answers to come with the authority one may want. I specifically want to know of any forums or alternative, which are focused on poetry and or prose fiction, perhaps with some left philosophy also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of this Stack Exchange site, if you want to engage in *discussion* about literature rather than strict Q&A with all the rules of the SE system, you can try dropping into [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=literature.stackexchange.com). The main Literature SE chatroom, [The Reading Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1037/the-reading-room), is reasonably active - not every hour, but at least every day there's usually some conversation. It's a great place to engage in discussion about literature with fellow enthusiasts, without the restrictions of the Q&A system. You could also create a [new chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new), but you'd need to actively invite people there in order to find anyone to discuss with.

For other options outside of SE, there are some recommendations in this previous meta post: [I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/768/17)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're asking for, but I've tried to address at least what I *think* you're asking.

Comment: ha yeah thanks... looks like reddit is the only mainstream option. that's frustrating. i wonder how long it will last.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117103/lets-start-a-literature-discussion-forum thanks